# Can we update a jar / war file in a deployed server and then reload the new jar / war file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, webserver, war

Can we update a jar / war file in a deployed server and then reload the new jar / war file ? 
if so how simple we can achieve this, and please if possible list web servers which support this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

All major Java EE Servlet containers support this. All that I've worked with anyway, which includes Glassfish, Tomcat, WebSphere, WebLogic and JRun.

I haven't used the other Oracle container, but I would think it does too.

That said, none of them support it all that reliably (they'll detect most changes, but there are certain types of class changes that will always require a restart), unless you're using [JavaRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/javarebel/) underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Just by copying the 'war' file in the Server domain folder will automatically deploy it. I have done it with glassfishv3.1

The path for windows is C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy

Once pasted another file gets created automatically [if the server is on] in the same directory

For the editing purposes the 'war' file can be opened with programs like WinRar or WinZip

Just open the files that you want to change and save it when the winrar asks for it.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and [Jetty](http://jetty.mortbay.com) will support a hot deploy. They simply monitor the deploy directory for changes, so you can just copy the `.war` file into that directory, and the server will undeploy/redeploy.

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm only looking at .wars. Where would you drop a .jar ? It's not a web app in itself, so are you looking to redeploy a common lib ?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss.  Just drop in the files in the correct location.